# Issue on Handling Back Button

Tags: android, android-intent

My App starts with a splash screen loading background data from remote server. After completion of data load, An Activity(say B) launched.
This activity B (A photo Gallery of different Animals), when pressed back launches SplashScreen, so inorder to solve this, i prompt user if it really wants to exit the app, if clicked yes, exit closes.

```
private void exitApp(){
      B.this.finish();
}
```

My issues comes here.
Since Activity B, when clicks on Particular Animals say DOG,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(B.this,C.class)
startActivity(Intent);
```

takes the user to Activity (C) reviews of particular Animals.
When back button is pressed on C, takes me to B, thats fine.
Since B has menu options, such as bookmark,Home.
i do Launch BOOKMARK as with

```
sartActivity(B.this, Bookmark.class);
```

Since BookMark has menu for HOME i.e Activity B.
And now when i pressed back, it prompts me to Exit but it does exit the app rather takes me to BOOKMARK.

Can i solve this issues? As i was reading the doc, i found

```
 `finishActivityFromChild(Activity, requestCode);`
```

can this help me achieve?

Let say when a user is prompted to exit the application. I simply want to remove all the stack of activities.
Can it be done?

Comment: you might be finishing Bookmark when clicking Home button, is it?

Comment: You mean in last case , when you presses back and accept on exit, it opens your bookmark page, Right?? if yes let me know can help u out!!

Comment: can u explain ur flow of activities in simple way eg A-->B--> C, that would be easy to sort out ur problem

Comment: @AnkitAwasthi yes you are rigth.

Comment: SEE MY ANSWER  and try that in your code

Comment: @ALL Let me put this way, i go through the activities. but when the user is ask to exit the application i simply want to remove all the stack of views. Can it be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add   below tag in your AndroidManifest.xml file under BookMark activity

```
 android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

and include below tag in your  HOME i.e Activity B.

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

and let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks it does solve my problem for now. Let me see if there's any other problem. Thank you all for you valuable suggestions.